# How to fetch the branch and the build number directly from TeamCity?

Tags: go, testing, teamcity, cicd, teamcity-9.0

I have a very large project that has lots of branches and multiple builds that are built continously. What I want is to run my automation tests written in Go such that they first fetch the build number as well as the branch from TeamCity and then based on some validations run the tests accordingly.

I had tried giving a build number directly from inside my code, but that is a flawed approach as it isn't able to figure out the branch it needs to look at to find the build.